# How to get a Diablos-Hardhorn?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I'm HR60,  and I'm trying to get a Diablos-Hardhorn, but I'm not having any luck finding one. How do I acquire a Diablos-Hardhorn?

Answer (score 7):

[Diablos Hardhorn](http://kiranico.com/en/mh3u/item/diablos-hardhorn) is one of the rarest rewards for defeating a G-rank ([Black](http://104.236.123.105/en/mh3u/monster/black-diablos)) [Diablos](http://104.236.123.105/en/mh3u/monster/diablos).

To even qualify to receive the hardhorn, you must break both it's horns during the hunt. This can be made somewhat easier by getting it to charge into certain 'softer' parts of rock walls, which will cause it to become temporarily stuck, allowing for a number of free hits on it's face/horns.

Once both horns are broken, and the Diablos is killed/captured, you will have a 5% chance to receive a Hardhorn per Diablos (7% per *Black* Diablos) that had both horns broken.

---

If you have access to it, the 7* Port quest "[[Advanced] Plain Dangerous](http://104.236.123.105/en/mh3u/quest/port/7/advanced-plain-dangerous)" is probably your best bet for obtaining Hardhorns if you are able to take down both a G-rank Sand Barioth and a Black Diablos (and deal with possible Volvidon/*Savage Deviljho* interference). This quest, upon completion, gives you two separate chances of 5% for a Diablos Hardhorn *in addition* to the 7% chance if you broke the Black Diablos's horns. That's roughly a 16% to get ***at least one*** Hardhorn in the reward box (9.75% if you didn't manage to break the horns).

Do keep in mind that even at a 16% chance, sometimes you just get streaks of bad luck. You could run that quest a dozen times and not see a single one, and someone else runs it with you and gets 3 in a single run. Random is random.

Comment: Thank you, but i still havent got it with the Combo: the Idol Mask, theKelbi bow(with a trick to breaking the horns), then "[Advanced] Plain Dangerous" and the tricks, "How to kill Sand-Barioth and Black Diablos"! now, when u r showing me a good trick, then r u the BEEEESSSSTTTT!!!(geeeeeeettttttttt dunked on!!!)

Comment: Wait... I think, i don't Need the answer of my question, 'cause i'm now playing MH4U ([Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate]) and no more tri! but you can help me by MH4U! I Need now just a Player, who's making with me some Arena - and hunting(Normal) Quests! -.- Fa'get 'bout it, ok?

Comment: When did loot drops become so complicated? I remembered it a lot simpler. The quest have a base loot that roll from a table, capturing will roll loots from another table, carving after killing from one, each part broken will roll loot from its table. Don't remember any item requiring multiple parts broken or boosted rates. By experience, if that item drop from broken horn each horn will give a separate chance of getting it thus both horns broken will result in a small chance getting two. Did it change when I did not notice?

Comment: @BenOng *shrug* AFAIK in the last few games, (depending on the monster) some parts have multiple stages before they are fully broken, often having an in-between state. Breaking the first stage of a part will usually still result in a shiny gathering point that is the same as the one from fully breaking it, but for the end-of-hunt loot tables you need to fully break them. I assume the horns were made to be the same way at some point.